# How to add data to Google table charts

Tags: javascript, for-loop, datatable, google-visualization

I want to build a table with Google Charts that will contain information about teams, what people are in the team and what roles they have inside the team.
One problem I have encountered is that some fields is empty in the database, but it should still be added to the same row in the table.

An example of how I want it to look is like this:

```
TeamName    Members Role    Contract    Country City
Joe Doe     Programmer      Own Staff   Greenland Nuuk
Jane Doe    Design
```

I have built this so far but the problem is that only one of my objects in the database have all information, so only that person was added in the table

```
function drawChart() {
          // Table-chart with the teams
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'TeamName');+
          data.addColumn('string', 'Members');
          data.addColumn('string', 'Role');
          data.addColumn('string', 'Contract');
          data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
          data.addColumn('string', 'City');

          _teams = []
          _object = []
          {% for obj in object_list %}
                {% for team in obj.team.items %}
                    {% for role in obj.role.items %}
                        {% for contract in obj.cont.items %}
                            {% for location in obj.loc.items %}
                           {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
         google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table-div'));
         table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
    }
```

Anyone have any idea of how I can solve this?

Comment: will you please share the code inside the `for` loops? where do you use `addRow`?

Comment: @WhiteHat I have removed the code since it didn't work as intended and hopefully can we find another way to make this work without using so many loops

Comment: can you somehow share a sample of --> `object_list`